# Remove LibreOffice version installed by dpkg -i *.deb

Tags: package-management, dpkg, uninstall, libreoffice

I have LibreOffice 5.4, had been installed by downloading the `_deb.tar.gz` and running `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` as it says in the readme.

I just downloaded LibreOffice 6 the same way and did the same process, expecting an over-write of 5.4 with 6. Instead now I have both. I have never gone the `sudo apt-get install` or PPA route because the latest ones were always out sooner in `_deb.tar.gz` and I frankly found the process smooth enough to never bother.

So, my OS doesn't really know that LibreOffice is even installed:

```
$ libreoffice --version
The program 'libreoffice' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install libreoffice-common
```

How does one remove a LibreOffice that's been installed the `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` way? Online I'm finding various answers that advise to remove it the `apt-get` way (ie assuming every existing LibreOffice out there has been installed the system way and not by dpkg... and they then advise how to install latest version by the dpkg way! Next time?)

Is it just about deleting off some files and folders? Is there something else to be done? Some config files to edit yada yada? I'm not doing direct-deleting yet, assuming some more steps may be needed. Oh and I have both 5.4 and 6 installed on my system, want to remove 5.4 only.

Comment: Please update your question with output of `dpkg -l | grep libreoffice`.

Comment: its ok I got it done by Synaptic Package Manager, see answer. `.deb` files are from https://www.libreoffice.org/ of course :D

Answer (score 2):

Found how to do it : **Synaptic Package Manager**. I had assumed that since sudo apt.. didn't know there was a libreoffice on board then even here it would be the same. But now I know this works differently.

I searched for "libreoffice" by name and it listed them all.. including not-installed but in-catalog ones <s>(1.6.0.3! oh boy now I know why they ask not to install from the official repositories and ask us to add PPAs..)</s>. The 5.4 and 6.0 ones were all checked. So I selected all the 5.4 ones, right-clicked and marked for complete removal. Pressed the Apply button, and now the older one is gone, I have 700MB more space on the drive, its shortcuts are gone and entries from Open With.. are also gone. Clean uninstall.

Comment: The one you think is old, (1.6.0.3) in not that old. It is 1:6.0.3, a 6.0.3 version built for ubuntu.

Comment: @Jean-Marie oh! My bad. Struck that part off. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: *Why don't you mark your own answer as definitive?*

Comment: I think other GUI software managers can list and uninstall the deb-installed  versions, like the default Ubuntu Gnome one, if that's what you use. I am in Kubuntu, and Discover, Muon and Apper all have that ability.

Answer (score 1):

As a complementary answer:

The OP asked about a situation where two versions of the program are both installed from deb. *When no version is installed from the repos or PPAs*, the command `libreoffice --version` will say no version is installed.

My situation is a bit different, with version 6.1.2 installed from repos and with 6.2 dev version installed from deb (in Kubuntu 18.10, where 6.2 doesn't seem to work, so I needed it removed), in which case `libreoffice --version` shows the former but not the latter.

As said in the OP's answer, a program like *Synaptic* will list them all though, whether installed from deb or from repos/PPAs.

In Qt desktops other tools like *Apper, Muon, Discover* will list them all. I think the Ubuntu Gnome software manager (that I cannot test) has the same capability.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the programs, you may or may not have to remove the old version, but chances are that such info won't be mentioned in the readmes or anywhere, so that you can happily lose an hour or two figuring out how to delete the older version. I have installed version 6.06 with `dpkg -i *.deb` since 5.2.7, which is the latest version for Debian Stretch's package manager, had stopped starting up (just displaying *Application error*).

I then carefully did `apt-get remove libreoffice` (not `libreoffice6.0`) and this of course removed the new version…

Comment: Well, that’s just what I did, folks. Sorry if my factual experience accompanied by a modest attempt at humour was such an offense to some. This sole downvote was enough for me to be put among the bad kids on this site and discouraged to answer again. Have a nice day.